# Creating new File in Typescript returns empty type even if type was specified

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to generate a mocked File for an Angular unit test and I face some problems.

Here is my code, on top of spec file:

```js
let content = "Hello Zip";
let data = new Blob([content], { type: 'application/zip' });
let arrayOfBlob = new Array<Blob>();
arrayOfBlob.push(data);
let applicationZip = new File(arrayOfBlob, "Mock.zip");
```

If I try to do:

```
console.log(applicationZip);
```

Here is the result:

> lastModified: 1492785142174
>
> lastModifiedDate: Fri Apr 21 2017 10:32:22 GMT-0400
>
> name:"Mock.zip"
>
> size:9
>
> **type: ""**
>
> webkitRelativePath:""
>
> proto: File

On of the method I want to create a test for must check the validity of file's mime type.

With my code, the type is always null. I tried to set it to plain/text for example and it doesn't change anything.

So I guess my File mock creation is somehow incorrect but I can't figure the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify the type as part of the File constructor. `File` accepts a [third parameter](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#file-constructor-params) where you can specify the type:

```
let applicationZip = new File(arrayOfBlob, "Mock.zip", { type: 'application/zip' });
```

Comment: Thanks I thought type would be "guessed" from Blob type